# Confusion between subsets and elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$.

(a) Is $\{1, 2\}$ an element of $A$, a subset of $A$, both or neither?

(b) Is $\{2, 3\}$ an element of $A$, a subset of $A$, both or neither?

(c) Is $1$ an element of $A$, a subset of $A$, both or neither?

Solution:

(a)

Let $B = \{1,2\}$

B is an element of A because it's in A. $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of A, because every element of B is in A

(b) Let $C = \{2,3\}$.

C is an element of A because it's in A. $\{2, 3\}$ is not a subset of A, because every element of C is not in A

(c) $1$ is an element in A. It's not a subset because it's not a set

Would this now be correct?

Comment: (a) is correct, (b) is an element but not a subset. (c) can't be a subset since it's not a set to begin with.

Comment: Okay fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)** This part is correct.

**(b)** In this part, it is true that $\{2,3\}$ is not an element of $A$. However, it is a subset since $2 \in A$ and $3 \in A$.

**(c)** In this part, it is true that $1 \in A$. But it is not subset since it is not even a set. If it was $\{1\}$, then it would have been a subset but not an elements of $A$.